# Difference between COMPILE_FLAGS and COMPILE_OPTIONS

Tags: cmake

What is the difference between

> COMPILE_FLAGS: Additional flags to use when compiling this target's sources.

and

> COMPILE_OPTIONS: List of options to pass to the compiler.

In terms of resulting VS2010 solution these commands produce the same result:

```
target_compile_options(target PRIVATE "/option=test1")
set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/option=test1")
set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "/option=test1")
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`COMPILE_OPTIONS` is a list, but `COMPILE_FLAGS` is a string.

```
set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES 
    COMPILE_OPTIONS "/option=test1;/option2=test2")
set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES 
    COMPILE_FLAGS "/option=test1 /option2=test2")
```

You can more-easily append to a list than to a string.

Also, `COMPILE_OPTIONS` is properly escaped, whereas some characters in `COMPILE_FLAGS` may need to be escaped manually or cause problems.

Comment: I was more wondering about difference between the target properties itself, not a way how to set them. question edited

Comment: I don't know what you're missing. The way to set the properties does not affect the fact that one is a string and the other is a list. Answer edited too.

Answer (score 2):

Can be used to the same end, but flags are associated with some target enviroment. So you could use different sets of flags for different enviroments.